# groupby array of hashes into array of hashes of arrays?

Tags: ruby, arrays

I am trying my hand at data manipulation in ruby.

Given this array of hashes

```
peepz = [
{
  :name => 'ted',
  :phone => '555-1234',
  :color => 'red'
},
{
  :name => 'bill',
  :phone => '555-2222',
  :color => 'green'
},
{
  :name => 'ted',
  :phone => '555-3333',
  :color => 'orange'
},
{
  :name => 'dan',
  :phone => '555-7777',
  :color => 'violet'
},
{
  :name => 'ted',
  :phone => '555-4444',
  :color => 'yellow'
},
{
  :name => 'dan',
  :phone => '555-6666',
  :color => 'orange'
}
];
```

I desire this output

```
peepz2 = [
  {
    :name => 'ted'
    :phone => ['555-1212','555-3333','555-4444']
    :color => ['red','orange','yellow']
  },
  {
    :name => 'bill'
    :phone => ['555-2222']
    :color => ['green']
  },
  {
    :name => 'dan'
    :phone => ['555-7777','555-6666']
    :color => ['violet','orange']
  },
]
```

here's what i have so far.

```
def groupbyer ( peepz, *fields )
    peepz.groupby do |peep|
      key = ''
      fields.each do |field|
        key += peep[field].to_s
      end
    end.each do |group|
      ????
    end
end

groupbyer(peepz, :name)
```

This method must be generalized.  it cannot hard code the fields of peepz

what is the nice ruby way to finish this?

Answer (score 4):

```
peepz
.group_by{|h| h[:name]}.values
.map{|a| a.inject{|h1, h2| h1.merge(h2){|k, v1, v2| k == :name ? v1 : [*v1, v2]}}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way uses the form of [Hash#update](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Hash.html#method-i-update) (aka `merge!`) that employs a block to determine the values of keys present in both hashes being merged:

**Code**

```
def peep_merge(peepz)
  peepz.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
         h.update(g[:name]=>(g.merge(g) { |*_,v|
           [v] })) { |_,oh,nh| oh.merge(nh) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } } }
       .values
       .each { |h| h[:name] = h[:name].first }
end
```

**Example**

For `peepz` given in the question:

```
peep_merge(peepz)
  #=> [{:name=>"ted",                   
  #     :phone=>["555-1234", "555-3333", "555-4444"],
  #     :color=>["red", "orange", "yellow"]},
  #    {:name=>"bill",
  #     :phone=>["555-2222"],
  #     :color=>["green"]},
  #    {:name=>"dan",
  #     :phone=>["555-7777", "555-6666"],
  #     :color=>["violet", "orange"]}]
```

**Explanation**

```
a = peepz.each_with_object({}) { |g,h|
      h.update(g[:name]=>(g.merge(g) { |*_,v|
        [v] })) { |_,oh,nh| oh.merge(nh) { |_,ov,nv| ov+nv } } }
  #=> {"ted" =>{:name=>["ted", "ted", "ted"],
  #             :phone=>["555-1234", "555-3333", "555-4444"],
  #             :color=>["red", "orange", "yellow"]},
  #    "bill"=>{:name=>["bill"],
  #             :phone=>["555-2222"],
  #             :color=>["green"]},
  #    "dan" =>{:name=>["dan", "dan"], 
  #             :phone=>["555-7777", "555-6666"],
  #             :color=>["violet", "orange"]}} 
b = a.values
  #=>         [{:name =>["ted", "ted", "ted"],
  #             :phone=>["555-1234", "555-3333", "555-4444"],
  #             :color=>["red", "orange", "yellow"]},
  #            {:name =>["bill"],
  #             :phone=>["555-2222"],
  #             :color=>["green"]},
  #            {:name =>["dan", "dan"],
  #             :phone=>["555-7777", "555-6666"],
  #             :color=>["violet", "orange"]}]
```

Lastly, to correct the values for the `:name` keys:

```
b.each { |h| h[:name] = h[:name].first }
```

provides the result shown in the example above.